# view datetime method parameter using sos

Tags: .net, debugging, windbg, sos

How do I view a datetime that is being passed in as a parameter?

I found this example on the internet but I am having problems understanding it?  I dont see where they use the output from clrstack at all, it just says "View the stack by dumping the memory from ESP forward:"

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsdebug/thread/4968f566-ef4c-4e29-ae23-6a17705178c4

after RSP i see lots of these.  Is there a real way to do this?

```
000000001d25f010 000007ff001872de method(System.DateTime)
    PARAMETERS:
        this = 0x00000000024ebcf8
        time = 0x48cfc7d6ced5a501

00000000`1d25ef28 000007fef1b11b6a 0000000000000001 0000000000000001 000000000002bf20 00000000024ebe18
00000000`1d25ef50 0000000000000002 00000000024ebeb8 00000000025022c0 000007fef1e37e24 00000000025022c0
00000000`1d25ef78 000000000002bf20 00000000024ebe01 000007fef2cb8d00 0000000000000000 0000000000000000
00000000`1d25efa0 0000000000000001 00000000024ebeb8 0000000000000000 000000001d25f0c0 0000000000000001
00000000`1d25efc8 000007fef2441085 0000000000000000 000007fef2cb9d69 0000000002409a88 0000000002409a88
00000000`1d25eff0 0000000002409a88 0000000000000000 00000000024ebff8 000007ff0018b2c1 48cfc7d6ced5a501
00000000`1d25f018 000000006b49d200 00000000024ebff8 000007ff0018b15f 000000006b49d200 0000010000000000
00000000`1d25f040 48cfc7d6ced5a501 0000000000000000 48cfc7d6638bd301 000000006b49d200 0000000100000000
00000000`1d25f068 48cfc7d6ced5a501 48cfc7d6638bd301 000000006b49d200 48cfc7d6ced5a501 0000000000000001
00000000`1d25f090 000000001d25f0c0 000007ff001872de 00000000024ebcf8 48cfc7d6ced5a501 00000000024ebdac
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download psscor2 or psscor4 (which is a superset of sos) from Microsoft and use this command:

### !help PrintDateTime

!PrintDateTime object_address

!PrintDateTime will print out the time of the System.DateTime object that is 
passed to it.

ps. psscor2 is for .net v2 and psscor4 is for .net v4

Comment: Note: psscor is not (yet) available for .NET 4.5 though.